# Escape dotnet resources in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to read dot ner reesources string in java script as mention below.

```
var resources = @Html.ResourceStrings("Home_General_", Resources.ResourceManager);
```

The above line will render all the resources (from Dot net resource file) which start with resource key as "Home_General_"

Some of the values from the resources are like "Hi "XYZ" are you there" i.e The string contains quotes character.

If the string has quotes the above call fails.

The one way to avoid this problem is escape the special character as `"Hi \"XYZ\" are you there"`

Any other way where we can avoid this, As I don't want to pollute my resource string with lot of escape (`\`) characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code like this to retrieve a single resource string:

```
var resourceXYZ = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("Home_General_XYZ")))';
```

We do the following:

1. We get the resource string via `Resources.ResourceManager.GetString()`.
2. We pass the result to `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` to escape any special characters in JavaScript.
3. We pass the result to `Html.Raw()` to prevent Razor from applying HTML encoding on this string.
4. We then output the text enclosed in single quote quaracters into the page.

---

The function `Html.ResourceStrings` is not a standard function that is part of MVC. Someone at your place must have written it. If you show us this code, we could tell you how to rewrite it to return valid JavaScript literals.

Answer (score 3):

You need to Javascript-escape any string when you render it as a Javascript string literal.

You must also remove the outer quotes from the string resource; that should be text, not a half-valid Javascript expression.

Comment: Code example would be a grat help

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `@Html.ResourcesString(...)` with [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx) which will handle all escape issues.

```
var resources = @HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.ResourceStrings("Home_General_", Resources.ResourceManager));
```

Comment: Html.ResourceStrings retunr MvcHtmlString and not string